# I can't select the selectors at detail level in a new screen of the Acumatica mobile application

Tags: acumatica

I am making my first attempts modifying the Acumatica mobile application and I have an issue.

I am inserting a new custom screen in the Acumatica mobile application, everything works fine except that I can't select the selectors at the detail level of the screen  (I press the selector and it does not display anything).
The customized screen has a header and a detail (similar to the sales order).

When I login to the mobile application the layout of the screen is correct, I can select all the fields of the header (including the selectors and I can select them without problem) the problem is when I go to the detail section. In the detail section I can select all the fields except the selectors in the mobile application.

The issue is in the container "DetalleDeMantenimiento" on the filed "AreaMantenimiento"

This is the code:

```
add screen TK010008 {
  add container "MantoHeadView" {
      formActionsToExpand = 1
      add layout "MantoHead" {
      displayName = "MantoHead"
      layout = "HeaderFirstAttachment"
      add field "MantoID"
      add field "Status"
      add field "Fecha"
    }
      add field "Equipo"{
      pickerType = Searchable
    }
        add field "Kilometraje"
        add field "Tipo"
        add field "CreatedBy"
        add containerAction "Insert" {
             icon = "system://Plus"
             behavior = Create
             redirect = True
 }
    add recordAction "Save"{
      behavior = save
    }
  add recordAction "GenerarSubOrdenes" {
    displayName = "GenerarSubOrdenes"
    icon = "system://RefreshCloud" behavior = Create
    }
      }
       
add container "DetalleDeMantenimiento" {
    formActionsToExpand = 1
    add  field "PuntoRevision"
    add  field "ComentarioEntrada"
    add field "AreaMantenimiento"{
      pickerType = Searchable
    }
    add containerAction "Insert" {
             icon = "system://Plus"
             behavior = Create
             redirect = True
 }
    add recordAction "Save"{
      behavior = save
    }
    }
        }
```

I think something is missing or something is not in the right place, could you please advise me?

Thank you very much,
Regards.